# Parametrized SQL Views with GeoServer and WFS

Tags: geoserver, sql, wfs, getfeature

I ran into this problem that is (almost) nowhere on the internet and thought I'd share the solution. GeoServer supports parametrized SQL views for Web Feature Services (WFS) but the [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html) leaves out a crucial fact (in fact its clear they cut and pasted the docs for the same page for WMS), since in a WFS all the requests are `GET` requests, they tell you to simply tack on to the query string a key value string of the form:

```
viewparams=keyOne:valueOne;keyTwo:valueTwo;
```

However in the `GetFeature` request, we have a `POST` request with an XML based payload and no obvious way to include the `viewparams` string. How does one do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a typical request payload for a GetFeature with the viewparams included in the xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<GetFeature 
 xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
 xmlns:gml='http://www.opengis.net/gml'
 xmlns:ogc='http://www.opengis.net/ogc'
 wfs:viewParams='keyOne:ValueOne;keyTwo:ValueTwo'
 xmlns:wfs='http://www.opengis.net/wfs'
 xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/wfs'
 xmlns:ccc='http://[URL]:8080/zipcodes'
 version='1.0.0' service='WFS' maxFeatures='100'>
 <wfs:Query typeName='ccc:myLayer' srsName='EPSG:4326'>
  <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc='http://www.opengis.net/ogc'>
   <ogc:BBOX>
    <ogc:PropertyName>ccc:geom</ogc:PropertyName>
    <gml:Box srsName='EPSG:4326'>
      <gml:coordinates>-126.24227121874098,25.286303720463525 -70.91512278125568,51.972617139892904</gml:coordinates>
    </gml:Box>
   </ogc:BBOX>
  </ogc:Filter>
 </wfs:Query>
</GetFeature>
```

In short, add a `wfs:viewParams` attribute to the main `GetFeature` xml element with the same key value string as above.

Comment: Correct, this has been supported at least since version 2.5.0 (maybe earlier versions too), see: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-5160?jql=project%20%3D%20GEOS%20AND%20text%20~%20%22support%20viewparams%22